# Internet Explorer 8 64bit and Selenium Not working

Tags: windows, windows-7, 64-bit, selenium

I am trying to get selenium tests to run. Yet every time I try to run a tests that should run IE I get a error on line 863 of htmlutils.js It says that I should disable my popup blocker. The thing is I went to IE tools-> turn of popup block.

So it is disabled and I get this error.

Is there something else I need to disable. I actually don't even know what version of Internet explorer it is running since I am using Windows 7 Pro 64bit version. So when I do use IE I use 64bit version but I am under the understanding if the site or something like that does not support 64bit it goes to 32bit.

So not sure what I need to do it to make it work.

This is the lines where it does

```
function openSeparateApplicationWindow(url, suppressMozillaWarning) {
    // resize the Selenium window itself
    window.resizeTo(1200, 500);
    window.moveTo(window.screenX, 0);

    var appWindow = window.open(url + '?start=true', 'selenium_main_app_window');
    if (appWindow == null) {
        var errorMessage = "Couldn't open app window; is the pop-up blocker enabled?"
        LOG.error(errorMessage);
        throw new Error("Couldn't open app window; is the pop-up blocker enabled?");
    }
```

Where is this log.error message stored? Maybe I can post that too.

Comment: You will probably get better results by posing this question on the Selenium support forums.

Comment: You can start selenium server with the -log flag, that will get you a more detailed output of the problem: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#selenium-server-logging

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar problem on Vista and IE8
I would get the same error message

```
Couldn't open app window; is the pop-up blocker enabled?"
```

Running my remote control as Admin wasn't an option for me, and also a poor idea from a  security perspective. 
So in the end I manage to solved this by changeing browser from "*ietha" to "*iexploreproxy"
grid_configuration.yml

```
hub:
  port: 4444
    ...
    - name: "Internet Explorer 8 on Vista"
      browser: "*iexploreproxy"
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can change browser string from the code:

```
ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexploreproxy", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Works like a charm. 
The only question remaing is if this somehow affects the outcome of the test cases. So far no, but I'll update this answer in case that would happen.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Using iexploreproxy it tries to open the following URL after start: `http://localhost:8003/selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=f44546a9dc584b69a1d20d539a8a037c&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8003%2Findex-test.php%2F&debugMode=false` which is invalid because there is no "selenium-server" url defined... any idea?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this on Windows 7 64bit.

My solution was:

1. Disable popup block.  - Select "Tools/Popup Blocker/Turn off pop-up blocker"
2. Disable IE protected mode. - Untick "Tools/Internet Options/Security/Enable protected mode"

It'd be better just to disable protected modes for known trusted hosts/addresses.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and seemed like a better solution than running as admin or moving to using a proxy.

Comment: Ha, just found this answer again. Still works and still seems like the best solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I added the local host to the trusted sites and disabled pop up blocking and the IE protected mode. And it still fails as couldn't open app window? What else do I need to do? It works fine for an admin but we can't run it like that as we're running it via selunit in our build server.

Comment: This did it for me, Windows7, IE8 64 bit. The popup blocker was already off, the "Enable protected mode" checkbox was what mattered.

Comment: Don't work for me at all. Win7, IE8, 32bit. I'm inside a company network.

Answer (score 8):

I was experiencing the same problem.  I ran the Selenium RC server as an administrator and everything worked fine.

Comment: Running the Selenium RC as an administrator solved the problem for me too.

Comment: How do you run it as an administrator? I'm using `java -jar selenium-server.jar`. I'm an administrator so I guess selenium is running under my account as well. Or should I run it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I, too, am experiencing this very problem on a Windows 7 64bit box, trying to run Selenium on it to test and ASP .Net MVC application, written in C#.

I am still trying to work out the answer for myself, but I thought I'd post here to tell you of a little progress I have made in getting *something* to work, albeit in Firefox instead of IE.

Here's the line I changed:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe", "http://www.bbc.co.uk/");
```

I would ideally like for this to work in Internet Explorer 8, but if for the moment, I can begin getting tests working and later change over to use IE again, then great.

Hope this helps for your problem with it all.

Comment: Hmm I have no problem running selenium in firefox or any other of the supported browser(opera,safari,chrome). It is just IE 8 that won't run.

Comment: One suggestion I found that I have not been able to try yet. Is to run the server in admin mode. Try that out that might work

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and have found another solution which works for me. Just use the *iexploreproxy setting in the browserString.

I used:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexploreproxy C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplorer.exe", "http://www.bbc.co.uk/");
```

I hope that works for others too :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 7 64bit IE8. The first step was to disable the IE popup blocker. Then, I got a message in the status bar saying that "Pop-ups were blocked on this page. Press the 'Ctrl' key to allow the pop-ups".

It turns out that the Google Toolbar was providing this feature. Disabling it solved the problem. View > Toolbars > Google to toggle.

John.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be doing this from JavaScriptMVC, there is a reference you need to change in \jmvc\plugins\test\drivers\selenium.js:

1) Change iexplore to iexploreproxy and you should get better results:

```
    msie : (/iexploreproxy/i).test(browserStartCommand),
```

2) At this point, you'll find that you still get the popup error, but a separate instance of IE has started. **Leave that IE window open** and restart the tests, but not Selenium.

3) Next, the windows should show up in the right place, but IE gives the annoying block active content warning. Allow the content to run and restart the tests, but not Selenium itself.

This is super clunky, but it at least gets you past that part. If I find more methodical ways to do these things I'll update as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can start the test when you disable the Security mode of Internet. Don´t know the correct name for it, but in dutch it is beveiligde modus.
I tried modifiing the security settings to dublicate this security mode, but couldn´t find the correct setting for it. It must therefor block more then you can set manually.