# Selenium Code Not Working for Internet Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium

I am trying to perform automation testing using Selenium with Java in Eclipse IDE.

My automation testing source code is given as follows:

**TestClass.java**

```
package testproject;

import login.*;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SearchTest st = new LoginTest();
        try {
            st.setUp();
            st.testNew();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**SearchTest.java**

```
package login;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SearchTest extends SeleneseTestBase {
    
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        setUp("http://www.google.com/", "*iexplore");
    }
    
    public void testNew() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "selenium rc");
        selenium.click("btnG");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Results * for selenium rc"));            
    }
}
```

I have a Windows 8 system and have downloaded the proper Selenium Web driver for Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome.

The problem here is that despite setting the environment variable and starting the Selenium RC server from Command Prompt by executing the jar file, the website (Google) is not opened. Instead of directing me to `http://www.google.com`, the RC server directs me to `C:\Users\rugved.mandrekar\AppData\Local\Temp\customProfileDir1b3a3fa718214e7cae8240f4cf54293e\core\Blank.html` as highlighted in the following screenshot:

[image: Incorrect URL]

I had created the above code a day ago and it was getting executed perfectly. Currently too, the test is performed in other browsers such as Chrome and Firefox. In other words when I change *iexplore in line 10 in the SearchTest.java file to firefox or chrome, the test gets executed. Also there is an error message in the Selenium console log which has started popping up from today. The screenshot of the error message is as follows:

[image: Error Message in Selenium Log Window]

Can anyone tell me where exactly am I going wrong? Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a pop up blocker enabled?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. No I don't have the pop up blocker enabled.

Comment: Cool, probably very silly question, but best to do the basic stuff first! IE is fiddly, are you running it as administrator? I'll look at the code now etc, but best to try the enviornmental stuff first. Also try in IE: click on “Sites” button and add the Urls of the application you are testing in “Add this website to the zone:” and clicking on “Add” button.  Does [any of this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517623/internet-explorer-8-64bit-and-selenium-not-working)

Comment: Sorry to double comment, try this `Internet Options > Security > uncheck the Enable Protected mode checkbox and try running the script.` Also run everything as Administrator, that means your IDE and the Browser.

Comment: what part did the trick? I'll add it as an answer so others can benefit from it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Internet Expolorer:**

- Click on “Sites” button and add the Urls of the application you are
  testing in `Add this website to the zone:` and clicking on `Add`
  button.
- Disable popup block. - Select `Tools/Popup Blocker/Turn off pop-up
  blocker`
- Disable IE protected mode. - Untick `Tools/Internet Options/Security/Enable protected mode`
- Ensure you run Internet Explorer and your IDE as **Administrator**.

**In the Code**

- Try changing the browser string to

`ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexploreproxy", "http://www.google.com/");`

[Credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517623/internet-explorer-8-64bit-and-selenium-not-working)

Comment: The second part of your answer helped me solve the problem as I had already turned my pop up blocker off. Thank you. :-)

Comment: My pleasure :) glad it helped. I'll be using Selenium in a new job in a few weeks, I'll probably have about a million questions!